# [Flask - ElasticBeansatalk]Error: chown /var/app/staging/himasui_app/himasui_venv/bin/python: no such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I develop a flask-web-app.
When I deploy the application to ElasticBeanstalk, The EB raises an Error.
I don't know the solution for the error.

```
An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/app_name/app_name_venv/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

***local.py(config)***
Content in config file is common to local and production, cuz i have no idea for coding production-config.
i think it is a factor of the Error.
can you tell me how to write config file for flask?

```py
import os

# Flask
DEBUG = True

# SQLAlchemy
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI         = 'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/app_development?charset=utf8'.format(**{
    'user'      : os.getenv('DB_USER', 'root'),
    'password'  : os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'host'      : os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
})
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS  = False
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO                 = False

# SECRET_KEY
SECRET_KEY = 'foo'

# BasicAuthUser
BASIC_AUTH_USER = 'admin'
BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD = 'admin1234'
```

***Directory-map***

```
app
├  __pycache__
|
├  elasticbeanstalk
|  └  config.yml
|
├  config
|  ├  __pycache__
|  ├  __init__.py
|  ├  local.py
|  └  production.py
|
├  functions
|  ├  func1
|  |  ├  __pycache__
|  |  ├  templates
|  |  ├  __init__.py
|  |  └  controller.py
|  ├  func2
|  ├  func3
|  └  …
|
├  app_venv
|  ├  bin
|  ├  include
|  ├  lib
|  └  pyvenv.cfg
|
├  migrations
|  ├  __pycache__
|  ├  versions
|  ├  alembic.ini
|  ├  env.py
|  ├  READEME
|  └  script.py.mako
|
├  models
|  ├  __pycache__
|  ├  __init__.py
|  ├  models.py
|  └  setting.py
|
├  static
|  ├  images
|  ├  javascript
|  └  stylesheets
|
├  templates
├  .DS_Store
├  .ebignore
├  .gitignore
├  application.py
├  database.py
├  httpauth.py
├  methods.py
├  requirements.txt
└  variable.py
```

Comment: Hi danayeon and welcome to SO ! Can you share your configuration file and how your project is organised ? It seems it has to do with path to files...

Comment: @cbo Thanks you comment! I edited the question!

Comment: Guess work : the app launch by executing the content of `/var/app/staging/app_name/app_name_venv/bin/python` so here I would check whether the `python`folder exists (apprently not) and put the required files there (ie in `app_name_venv/bin/python`).

Comment: There could also be the problem of the directory `app` instead of `app_name`.

Comment: @cbo Thank you. You mean I should put `/var/app/staging/app_name/app_name_venv/bin/python` the app directory in local server?

Comment: yes (wild guess maybe)

Comment: sorry but how can i put it on?